# Fatal error in member function

Tags: magento-1.8

Getting an error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isVisibleInSiteVisibility() In
>   template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml on line 60

Here is code:

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what are you getting in `$_item` ?

Comment: Accept the answer If you find my answer helpful @Pradip

Answer (score 0):

I think in your `quote` you have multiple product in `cart`, so you can check with this below condition,

```
if($_item->getProduct()->getTypeId() === 'bundle'){
     $_item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
}
```